# Mac OS X Caps Locks Key Flash on HD Activity

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, capslock

Is there an application or plug-in that can make the Mac OS X caps locks key flash on HD Activity. I have switched the binding on <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> so light is sitting there idle.

If this doesn't exist is it possible to create? I am fairly proficient with Ruby and wouldn't mind trying out Objective C. It is not beyond the realms of possibility I could program something myself.